# How to remove items from the CheckListBox (windows application) from another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I am developing a windows app in which i need to add items in the checklist-box at run-time from the separate thread, for that i used :

```
if (chkLBClientsList.InvokeRequired)
   chkLBClientsList.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate{chkLBClientsList.Items.Add(GetHostNameByIpAddress(ipAddress));}));
```

later in the application i need to remove the items from the checklist-box and for that i am using same logic :

```
if (chkLBClientsList.InvokeRequired)
   chkLBClientsList.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { chkLBClientsList.Items.Remove(GetHostNameByIpAddress(GetIpAddress(client))); }));
```

but it's not working....because this statement `chkLBClientsList.InvokeRequired`  returns FALSE value.

Please tell me how to solve this problem ?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you're in another thread? Put an else condition and just remove it

Comment: Agreed that you are probably on the main thread already. Are you calling from a System.Windows.Forms.Timer event? Those are on the main thread. Also if you are calling from a System.Timers.Timer event, you may have set the SynchronizingObject to an object in your main thread, in which case you're also ok.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel : Yes, i am in another thread. Your trick will work but i wanted to know that why "chkLBClientsList.InvokeRequired" return a false value?

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17678071/2530848). is false because you're creating instance of `chkLBClientsList` itself in another thread. not UI thread

Comment: You both are right, i am on the main thread already not in another thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Control.InvokeRequired` returns **false** when you are already on the UI thread. Try this:

```
delegate method = new MethodInvoker(delegate
{ 
    chkLBClientsList.Items.Remove(GetHostNameByIpAddress(GetIpAddress(client))); 
};
if (chkLBClientsList.InvokeRequired)
   chkLBClientsList.Invoke(method));
else method();
```

If `InvokeRequired` is **false**, just do the work without invoking.

Obviously, you will need to do similar for your *Add* method.

EDIT - the MSDN documentation for InvokeRequired would have been a great place for you to start. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx

> **Control.InvokeRequired Property**
>
> Gets a value indicating whether the caller must call an invoke method
>   when making method calls to the control because the caller is on a
>   different thread than the one the control was created on.